# Moveit- effect of set goal tolerance on performace?

Tags: moveit, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am using moveit with a UR5 robotic arm. I have joint angle goals to reach. My question is that
does setting a larger goal tolerance using the function move_group.setGoalTolerance(x) helps in increasing the probability of finding a plan in a constraint environment with obstacles . Has anyone played around or experimented with this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271833/moveit--effect-of-set-goal-tolerance-on-performace?/) by [Anirudh_s](https://answers.ros.org/users/29491/anirudh_s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2017-09-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-03**:
Also on [moveit-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/moveit-users/fXcMhk6jZd8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have not experimented with this a lot, but the main application of the tolerances is with Pose targets.
If you use bigger tolerances with JointConstraints, you can get rather unintuitive results because the tolerance applies *per joint*.

You might get better results in this case if your actual goal state is in collision, but part of the relaxation is not.
I'm not sure it's the best idea to rely on this though, instead of setting toleranced Pose targets.

For the default planner in kinetic (RRTConnect) I do not believe it should have much of an influence on the actual trajectory planning process, because it's goal-biased either way.

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2017-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1